# Generate a dashboard using VBA and java

Tags: java, excel

I am working on a dashboard project with the use of excel and java GUI. I would like to find out from the community if there is anyway I can collect data from various columns and worksheet in the excel and transfer it to another excel which would then generate the dashboard and open it with a click of the open button. Can I ask for sample codes because I am still quite a newbie when it comes to solo IT project. Thanks.

Okay. I need code example as guide on how to read data from multiple selected excel sheet that is chosen by a user from a JList and then when i click okay, it will put all the datas into a single excel dashboard template that I have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://poi.apache.org. This is a library that allows you to read and write Excel files. They have a lot of examples on their website on how to work with Excel files: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html. This should get you started to read from one file, and write to another file.